# Writing more succinct Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lines `1.` and `5.` below are too long (my understanding is that 80 characters is the recommended cut-off). What would be the best way to write this code; **specifically the conditionals' structure -- what are some alternative code formatting options**?

```
if @user.authenticate(params[:current_password]) && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user, notice:["Profile update successful."]
else
  flash.now[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages unless @user.errors.full_messages.empty?
  render :edit
end
```

Thanks!

### Update

If it's helpful, just ignore my code. I'm mostly interested in options for conditional structures and their formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `&&` and `||` you can split a conditional over several lines:

```
if @user.authenticate(params[:current_password]) && 
   @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
     # I line up the conditionals
     # and indent the code after the conditionals further
     # just for clarity
else
  # ...
```

but if you find someone with a text editor that doesn't wrap lines beyond 80 chars, my advice would be to tell them to get one that does or accept responsibility for their decisions.

Comment: The 80 character width is about best practices, readability, preference, and printability.

Comment: back in the 70's I'm sure it made sense ;)

Answer (score 2):

Line 5 can be deleted altogether. No need to use the flash when rendering. It's only necessary when redirecting. For the authentication you may want to set up a [`before_filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). With this your code can look like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_logged_in_user, :only => [:edit, :update]

  # Note: @user is set in require_logged_in_user
  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Profile update successful."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def require_logged_in_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to '/login' unless @user.authenticate(params[:current_password])
  end
end
```

Comment: this could be a good way to add a `before_filter`, but it has to be used only on `:update`, because `:update` should not have the params `:current_password`. So it may be overkill to define a before_filter here

Comment: I don't know his code. This is just an example of how `before_filter` can be used.

Comment: "No need to use the flash when rendering". It's a common pattern to let Rails show the error messages in the flash taking them from the object, but this doesn't mean you cannot set your own flash if you need to. But it's good to mention it anyway.

Comment: Those validation errors are not in the flash. He's unnecessarily putting them in the flash, but originally they are not. The reason for using the flash is for any messages to persist across requests. When redirecting you do two requests, but when rendering a template it's only one request, so even though it's possible to use the flash IMO you shouldn't.

Comment: @Mischa Right now all my messages are being passed via flash, but I need to create more options. I like your point about not using flash for something it's not intended for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are merging two conditions that IMO should be treated separately (keeping clean conditional branches is very important). I'd write:

```
if !@user.authenticate(params[:current_password]) 
  flash[:error] = "Authentication failed"
  render :edit
elsif !@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  # are you sure about this one? Rails helpers should show these errors.
  flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  render :edit
else
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user, notice: "Profile update successful"
end
```

Comment: Awesome, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

About the :

```
flash.now[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages unless @user.errors.full_messages.empty?
```

You don't have to check if the full_messages are empty, the flash should not be rendered when you pass it an empty array.

But personally, I'll try to use only "banged" methods, and rescue them:

```
begin
  @user.authenticate!(params[:current_password])
  @user.update_attributes!(params[:user])
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user, notice: "Profile update successful"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e # for example
  flash.now[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
  render :edit
end
```

But it might be just a personal taste.

Comment: A `authenticate!` method is unlikely to raise a `RecordInvalid`. Not saying rescuing here is bad, but the common accepted idiom in Rails controllers is to use conditionals (which IMO are more clear indeed).

Comment: Exceptions should be exceptional, IMO. There's nothing exceptional about a user failing authentication.